# JsonSerializer: How to create a list in a json without involve elements in French braces?

Tags: json, objectmapper, jsonserializer

I'm using JsonSerializer to format a Json in Java but I need a formatting in particular. I need formatting like this:

```
    {
        "atividades": {
            "atividade": {
                "numeroPA": "1350131018010243103A",
                "numero": "1350131018010243103A001"
            },
            "atividade": {
                "numeroPA": "1350131018010243103A",
                "numero": "1350131018010243103A002"
            }
        }

}
```

However I am getting a json like this:

```
{
    "atividades": [
        {
            "atividade": {
                "numeroPa": "1350131018010243103A",
                "numero": "1350131018010243103A001"
            }
        },
        {
            "atividade": {
                "numeroPa": "1350131018010243103A",
                "numero": "1350131018010243103A002"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a specific need of the project. I wonder if any of you have been through this and if you ever managed to solve it.

Below is the code that generates this json:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "atividade")
@JsonRootName(value = "atividade")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"numeroPa", "numero"})
public class NormaAtividadeDTO implements INormaAtividadeERP {

    private String numeroPa;
    private String numero;

    @JsonProperty("numeroPa")
    public String getNumeroPa() {
        return numeroPa;
    }

    public void setNumeroPa(String numeroPa) {
        this.numeroPa = numeroPa;
    }

    @JsonProperty("numero")
    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

}

public class NormaAtividadeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<NormaAtividadeDTO>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<NormaAtividadeDTO> pLstNormaAtividade, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeStartArray();

        for (NormaAtividadeDTO lNormaAtividadeDTO : pLstNormaAtividade) {

            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField("atividade", lNormaAtividadeDTO);
            gen.writeEndObject();

        }

        gen.writeEndArray();

    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"atividades"})
public class NormaAtividadeTransacaoDTO implements INormaAtividadeTransacaoERP {

    @XmlElement(name = "atividades")
    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = NormaAtividadeDTO.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = NormaAtividadeSerializer.class)
    private List<NormaAtividadeDTO> lstNormaAtividadeDTO = new ArrayList<NormaAtividadeDTO>();

    @JsonProperty("atividades")
    public List<NormaAtividadeDTO> getLstNormaAtividadeDTO() {
        return lstNormaAtividadeDTO;
    }

    public void setLstNormaAtividadeDTO(List<NormaAtividadeDTO> lstNormaAtividadeDTO) {
        this.lstNormaAtividadeDTO = lstNormaAtividadeDTO;
    }

}

json = objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(pObject);
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you also include what type of json mapping library is being used?

Comment: Your required formatting is not legal JSON. I can tell because multiple elements with the same name "atividade" appear as children of one node; this is only legal if they are array elements. The code confirms it: List<NormalAtividadeDTO> serializes into an array, which in JSON is represented within square brackets. If you put your required example into any JSON formatter (like Notepad++ with the JSON Viewer plugin), it will show it as not valid.